# Set up an IP whitelist programatically on a Linux server

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, ufw

I am fairly new to Linux

I have a situation where only registered website members should be allowed to access the server when attempting to login.

What I need to do is whitelist an IP automatically upon account creation and login and then feed that whitelist to my server firewall so it can check next time the registered user tries to login.

Is there any recommendations or tips on the best way to achieve this? Also, what would be the best linux distribution for this task?

Thank you!

Comment: 1/ how is the initial login happening if not yet whitelisted? 2/ How do you handle an user whose ISP keeps changing its IP address (or changes ISP or...)?

Comment: @A.B through the initial registration and the changing IPs are updated through logging in their new IP is checked against the current list if it's not on there, it gets added.

Comment: All that's gonna do is create a list of IPs that have ever been used to successfully log into accounts.  That list is probably already on your system.  On Debian, things like `sshd` will generate a log line with the IP each time someone logs in in `/var/log/auth.log` I think.  So you just need a script or program parsing that file, or you can tell `logrotate` to email the logs every once in a while too.  Look into `fail2ban` if you want to block IPs after repeated login failures.